# "Долго вытираю на столе от пыли тяжёлые, добротные папки", - нет двусмыслицы?

Tags: синтаксис, порядок-слов

> Долго вытираю на столе от пыли тяжёлые, добротные папки.

От пыли тяжёлые...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для носителей языка никакой двусмысленности нет (где? от чего?), задумается если только иностранец, и то вряд ли: чтобы подумать, что они **тяжёлые от пыли**, порядок слов должен быть именно таким (прямой, а не обратный).

Вряд ли более удачным будет с перестановкой: *Долго вытираю от пыли на столе  тяжёлые, добротные папки*, там будет "**от пыли на столе**". И заменить **от пыли** на **пыльные** тоже не очень удачное решение, так что пусть останется исходное.

Answer (score 1):

Двусмыслицы нет. Понятно, что *вытирает от пыли*.

Читая предложение, невозможно представить "*от пыли тяжёлые, добротные папки*". С большой натяжкой можно допустить, что они от пыли тяжёлые, но уж никак "от пыли... добротные" папки быть не могут.  *Добротные*, *тяжёлые* у вас через запятую, употреблены как однородные, и если допустить, что *от пыли* - это обстоятельство причины, то получается, что и добротные тоже от пыли. Это абсурд). Предложение построено правильно.